# MongoDB - admin user not authorized on sandbox plan

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I am trying to upgrade my sandbox database server version to 4.x.x. It is now at 3.6.6

In order to do that, I need to create an admin user.

So I connect to the mongo shell and I run the following :

```
db.createUser( { user: "admin", pwd: "password", roles: [ { role: "root", db: "mydatabasename" } ] } );
```

However, I get the following error :

```
Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command
```

It's been hours I am trying to figure out this issue. Other stackoverflow related questions don't solve it.

I am wondering if it is even possible to do so on a non dedicated database server. If not, how can I upgrade the server version ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is first ever user you're trying to connect in DB, you need to use "Localhost Exception":

> The localhost exception allows you to enable access control and then
>   create the first user in the system. With the localhost exception,
>   after you enable access control, connect to the localhost interface
>   and create the first user in the admin database. The first user must
>   have privileges to create other users, such as a user with the
>   userAdmin or userAdminAnyDatabase role

Create a user as follows:

```
use admin;
db.createUser( { user: "userAdminAnyDB", pwd: "password", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] } );

db.auth("userAdminAnyDB", "password")
```

Once you successfully login using userAdminAnyDB credentials, create a required for your Db deployment.

```
db.createUser( { user: "admin", pwd: "password", roles: [ { role: "root", db: "mydatabasename" } ] } );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! How do I use Localhost Exception ?

Comment: Following the first set of commands, I get : 
`Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on mydatabasename to execute command { createUser: "userAdminAnyDB", pwd: "xxx", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]`

Comment: I am using mlab and have already 2 users created via mlab but I doubt they have admin privileges. I am not even sure if this is the same users we're talking about via mongo shell

Comment: If users are already created, you need to login using user who has privileges to create user and grant admin privileges

Comment: None of them has admin privileges. I am not allowed to grant them admin privileges neither (error raised)

Comment: Looks like its available only with Dedicated plans, if you have so: https://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#admin-user